# Sending Email through CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

I want to send a mail through Tank Auth(a CodeIgniter library)

I am getting the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport
>   "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1689

i am using gmail

my php.ini file has the line without comment

> extension=php_openssl.dll

some conf in Email.php:

```
var $useragent      = "CodeIgniter";    
var $mailpath       = "/usr/sbin/sendmail";//i dont know what should i write here
var       $protocol     = "smtp";   
var $smtp_host      = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";        
var $smtp_user      = "mymail@gmail.com";
var $smtp_pass      = "mypass";
var $smtp_port      = "465";    
var $smtp_timeout   = 30;
var $smtp_crypto    = "";
var $wordwrap       = TRUE;         
var $wrapchars      = "76";         
var $mailtype       = "text";       
var $charset        = "utf-8";      
var $multipart      = "mixed";  
var       $alt_message  = '';       
var $validate       = FALSE;    
var $priority       = "3";      
var $newline        = "\r\n";       
var       $crlf     = "\n";
```

where might the problem be?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705856/socket-transport-ssl-in-php-not-enabled

Comment: No chance for now, i can not see php logs too :S

Answer (score 0):

I would try and reinstall openssl extension on windows http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

edit your code line from

```
var $smtp_host  = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

to

```
var $smtp_host  = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";
```

i think it will work

Answer (score 0):

To use Google SMTP in CodeIgniter you need to make 2 (two) changes into your Gmail account setting: (N.B. Please be aware that it is now easier for an attacker to break into your account -says Google)

1. Set off 2-step Verification.
2. Allow less secure apps: ON (or Enable)