# Fetch file from https only server

Tags: php, https

I have a small script which uses curl and retrives specific contents from a defined url. I had this tested on my localhost and it worked.

Now I have to retrive data from a HTTPS-only website (plus, the certificate is invalid, but I know the owners) from my free hosting, but the myserver neither supports `CURL` nor  `file_get_contents("https://other-server.com")` function. By the way, `http://other-server.com` isn't accesible.

Is there any method to fetch a file from this server using the HTTPS port, but with HTTP protocol? Or is there some method to use HTTPS, altough my server doesn't support it? (It isn't my server, I haven't access to its configuration)

Comment: There's lots of free hosting out there; why not find one that does?

Comment: Sounds like you may need to find another host who allows CURL or `file_get_contents()` access to remote servers. (And maybe suggest to the remote server owners to update their SSL certificate.)

Comment: You might try `wget https://other-server.com`... but it sounds like this particular host doesn't want you to make outbound connections.  Find one that allows it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://other-server.com", 443, $errno, $errstr);
if(!$fp) die($errno. " : " . $errstr);
$send = 
 "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n".
 "Host:other-server.com\r\n".
 "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n".
 "\r\n";

fwrite($fp, $send);
while(!feof($fp)) {
  echo fread($fp, 512);
}

?>
```

Should you run into 'ssl transport not available error message', see [Socket transport "ssl" in PHP not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705856/socket-transport-ssl-in-php-not-enabled)

If your host is external and perhaps a free webhosting service, you are fresh out of luck.. Best option would be to figure out which webhosts has the SSL transport enabled - otherwise the working with HTTPS protocol simply will not comply.

Your last 'out' is to try to load extension into PHP language dynamically. You will need the excact extension (dll/so) which matches

1. the PHP version on host (see phpinfo).
2. the CPU architechture of host (unix, see `passthru("cat /proc/cpuinfo");`), e.g. amd64,i386..
3. the OS 'layout', .dll is for a windows host (IIS etc) and .so for UNIX.

Funcition to use is `dl` aka dynamic-link to load the library. For windows host, you will need `php_openssl.dll` and `php_sockets.dll` - and in turn for UNIX, OOops - you would need to recompile php core..

Happy hacking :)

[php-man-pages](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php)

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, but... Nope: `-1219506188 : Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`. That is the 'ssl transport not available error message', but as I said, I am not able to modify servers config (plus, it has `exec` and `system` disabled, so wget doesn't work either). Many other people will find this sollution usefull, but I will problably find some other freehosting server. Have you got any suggestions? (With freehosting I mean I'm not going to pay anything)

Comment: Well, im not going to advertise any services (as im about to start my own :) but a simple google search against "free web hotel" would do the trick, then cycle through until my test-script doesnt throw error.