# Error updating dependencies composer

Tags: symfony, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

When I try to update, I get this error:

```
C:\wamp\www\bwon>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/finder (2.3.x-dev v2.3.0)
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://nodeload.github.com/symfony/Finder/zip/v2.3.0" file could not b
  e downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

Is this a GitHub problem or composer problem? I didn't have trouble before with updating/downloading composer packages.

Comment: possibly one of the answers here will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/1705856/210547

Comment: Thanx! this answer helped! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13601542/2449088)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem i solve it by enabling PHP_OPENSSL.dll

If you have mac then just run console comand

```
sudo port install php5-openssl
```

And that's all

Best,
Antonio