# Unable to send email from localhost in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, localhost

I am trying to send email in codeigniter on localhost, But it shows following error. I have configured the email library and gmail account. any one have solution for this.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to      find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962849/unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-ssl-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you

Answer (score 0):

> you getting this error

```
unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465
```

> because smtp is not working on localhost if u want to check whether
>   mail is send or not than u have to on live hosting server