# PHP verify failed with LetsEncrypt

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Having an issue when trying to read a stream :

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(
    ['http' => ['timeout' => (float) $this->options['timeout']]]
));
```

> SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>
> error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Before anyone answers i am not going to do

```
 "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
```

Am hoping someone else has used letsencrypt and has some proper way of making sure its validated.

feel free to check my cert on my domain `lukepolo.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

openssl.cafile= 
curl.cainfo=

in your php.ini , you need both

Comment: Hm. Doesn't help, if one doesn't know senseful values for these options.

Comment: you need to set the paths to your ca file

Comment: I'm totally aware of this. But which certificate do i point to?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to install the CA certificate ([this page has links to download the CA file](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/)). You might have to try each of the various signed to get it to work. Get the PEM version and save it to your server and then change your code like so

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(
    [
        'http' => ['timeout' => (float) $this->options['timeout']],
        'ssl' => ['cafile' => '/path/to/file.pem']
    ]
));
```

Comment: Im assuming i would just use the ISRG Root X1 pem file since the others are just intermediates.

Which i've tried but seems to still fail. Am i suppose to combine them somehow?

Comment: No, you want the intermediates. Your problem is that the server can't get the chain to validate the certificate. So you need the CA, or Certificate Authority

Comment: Gotcha, yah tried to chain them and still same issue. Not sure why this is being such a pain

Comment: Do you have command line access to your server? And is it Linux?

Comment: Yes and yes (ubuntu)

Comment: https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt/issues/609

I found this which is similar

Comment: Interesting. Ran this on a vanilla VM I have `openssl s_client -connect lukepolo.com:443` and got `Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)` (ssllabs.com says it's OK so no clue there)

Comment: you will need to specify the server name as well 

````openssl s_client -showcerts -connect lukepolo.com:443 -servername lukepolo.com````

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99242/discussion-between-lukepolo-and-machavity).

Comment: I fixed it so you wont have todo the --servername anymore

Comment: Final Solution is to make sure you do

openssl.cafile=
curl.cainfo=
in your php.ini