# Sending email in CodeIgniter not working

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

I am trying to send email using SMTP in CodeIgniter but it is not working. The code is as follows:

```
public function sendMail(){
    $config = array(
        'protocol'=>'smtp',
        'smtp_host'=>'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port'=>465,
        'smtp_user'=>'********@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass'=>'*********',
        'mailpath'=> "/usr/sbin/sendmail",
        'mailtype'=>'html',
        'charset'   => 'utf-8',
        'send_multipart'=>FALSE
    );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->load->library('encrypt',$config);

    $this->email->from('******@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to('******@gmail.com');
    $this->email->cc('******@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    if($this->email->send()){
        echo "Email sent success";
    }else{
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

I tried almost everything I found in the internet especially previous stack questions, but nothing seems to work. I am getting the usual error.

### Severity: Warning Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. )

**Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 2023
The following SMTP error was encountered: 10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203839/fsockopen-unable-to-connect-to-ssl-smtp-gmail-com465

Comment: I've already tried this link, it doesn't work in my code.

Comment: check ur php.ini file enable extension=php_openssl.dll

Answer (score 0):

things look correct, can you verify your php_openssl.dll is open, 
you can verify by using function

```
phpinfo()
```

if you find false, then uncomment the line

```
php_openssl.dll in php.ini
```

hope this work.

Comment: The php_openssl.dll is uncommented, but still the problem pertains.

Comment: add "smtp_crypto" in your config, the possible options are "  'tls' or 'ssl' "