# Codeigniter Email Cant Send Properly

Tags: php

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2023
```

With CodeIgniter, I can't send email.

Backtrace:

```
File: /home/vnmedical/public_html/application/controllers/Enquiry.php
Line: 59
Function: send

File: /home/vnmedical/public_html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: This might be helpful for you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962849/unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-ssl-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions.