# Extension missing: openssl Message could not be sent

Tags: php, ssl, dll, phpmailer

I am using the web-hosting site biz.ht. To send emails I have setup PHPMailer, I have tested it on localhost and it works fine, however when I try on the web-server. I gives me the error

*Extension missing: openssl Message could not be sent.*

Can someone please help me, the php.ini for biz.ht is here.

PHP 7.1.0

```
[PHP]
engine = On
cgi.check_shebang_line = 1
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
cgi.discard_path=1
cgi.force_redirect=0
date.timezone=UTC
;cgi.redirect_status_env = REMOTE_ADDR

short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision    =  12
y2k_compliance = On
output_buffering = Off
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func=
serialize_precision = 100

safe_mode = Off
safe_mode_gid = Off
safe_mode_include_dir =        
safe_mode_exec_dir =
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH

;disable_functions = highlight_file, diskfreespace, exec, passthru, system, popen, fsockopen, pfsockpen, show_source, php_uname, ini_alter, ini_restore, getrusage, get_current_user, set_time_limit, getmyuid, getmypid, dl, leak, listen, chown, chmod, chgrp, realpath, tmpfile, link 
disable_functions = 

disable_classes =
expose_php = Off

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = Off

log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off

report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off

;error_prepend_string = ""

variables_order = "EGPCS"
;register_globals = On
register_argc_argv = On

post_max_size = 20M
memory_limit = 64M
gpc_order = "GPC"


magic_quotes_runtime = Off    
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
;auto_prepend_file = /var/www/index.php

;auto_append_file =

default_mimetype = "text/html"

doc_root = 
user_dir = 
enable_dl = On

file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
upload_max_filesize = 15M
allow_url_fopen = On
default_socket_timeout = 60

[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables  = Off

[mail function]
sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/sendmail -oi -t

[Java]

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
;odbc.allow_persistent = On
;odbc.check_persistent = On
;odbc.max_persistent = -1
;odbc.max_links = -1  
;odbc.defaultlrl = 4096  
;odbc.defaultbinmode = 1  

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_persistent = Off
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port = 3306
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 10
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
;mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = On

[mSQL]
;msql.allow_persistent = On
;msql.max_persistent = -1
;msql.max_links = -1

[PostgresSQL]
;pgsql.allow_persistent = On
;pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off 
;pgsql.max_persistent = -1
;pgsql.max_links = -1
;pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
;pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase]
;sybase.allow_persistent = On
;sybase.max_persistent = -1
;sybase.max_links = -1
;sybase.min_error_severity = 10
;sybase.min_message_severity = 10
;sybase.compatability_mode = Off

[Sybase-CT]
;sybct.allow_persistent = On
;sybct.max_persistent = -1
;sybct.max_links = -1
;sybct.min_server_severity = 10
;sybct.min_client_severity = 10

[dbx]
;dbx.colnames_case = "unchanged"

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[browscap]

[Informix]
;ifx.default_host =
;ifx.default_user =
;ifx.default_password =
;ifx.allow_persistent = On
;ifx.max_persistent = -1
;ifx.max_links = -1
;ifx.textasvarchar = 0
;ifx.byteasvarchar = 0
;ifx.charasvarchar = 0
;ifx.blobinfile = 0
;ifx.nullformat = 0

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
;session.save_handler=mm
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_divisor     = 100
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

session.bug_compat_42 = 1
session.bug_compat_warn = 1

session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =

session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.save_path = /tmp

url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="

[MSSQL]
;mssql.allow_persistent = On
;mssql.max_persistent = -1
;mssql.max_links = -1
;mssql.min_error_severity = 10
;mssql.min_message_severity = 10
;mssql.compatability_mode = Off
;mssql.secure_connection = Off

[Assertion]

[Ingres II]
;ingres.allow_persistent = On
;ingres.max_persistent = -1
;ingres.max_links = -1
;ingres.default_database =
;ingres.default_user =
;ingres.default_password =

[Verisign Payflow Pro]
pfpro.defaulthost = "test-payflow.verisign.com"
pfpro.defaultport = 443
pfpro.defaulttimeout = 30

[com]

[Printer]

[mbstring]

[FrontBase]

[Crack]

[exif]

[Pdo]
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so

[extensions]

;extension=apc.so
;apc.optimization = 3
;apc.slam_defense = 75
;  extension=apc.so
;  apc.enabled=1
;  apc.shm_segments=1
;  apc.optimization=0
;  apc.shm_size=16
;  apc.ttl=7200
;  apc.user_ttl=7200
;  apc.num_files_hint=1024
;  apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
;  apc.enable_cli=1

extension=curl.so
;extension=ftp.so
;extension=id3.so
;extension=imagick.so
;extension=imap.so
;extension=openssl.so
;extension=intl.so
extension=pgsql.so
;extension=soap.so
;extension=xsl.so
;extension=yaml.so
;extension=memcached.so
;extension=memcache.so
;extension=gmp.so
;extension=mongo.so
;extension=mongodb.so

; Uncomment the line below to enable Ioncube Loader:
;zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so
; Uncomment the line below to enable ZendGuardLoader:
;zend_extension=/usr/local/ZendGuardLoader-php-5.3-linux-glibc23-i386/php-5.3.x/ZendGuardLoader.so
;zend_loader.disable_licensing=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a server config question rather than code. Your php.ini won't help much, but if you run `phpinfo()` or `php -m` you'll probably find that you're missing [PHP's openssl extension](http://php.net/openssl). So you just need to enable it, something which is probably a simple 'apt-get install php71-openssl`, depending on your server. you'll find many descriptions of how to enable it, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705856/socket-transport-ssl-in-php-not-enabled).